# Limit of function with log

Tags: limits, functions

Does $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 1^{+}} \ln(3x-3)$ exist in real numbers ( and it's $-\infty$) or is it a complex solution?

Comment: Yes. It exists and is $-\infty$. No complex numbers involved

Comment: The limit is  $-\infty,$ but it does not “exist in the real numbers.” $-\infty$ is not a real number, it is part of the “extended real line.”

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$\ln(3x-3) = \ln(3(x-1)) = \ln(3) + \ln(x-1)$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\to 1^+} \ln(x-1) = \lim_{x\to 0^+} \ln(x) = -\infty.
$$

Comment: @Raffaele I don't see why it's not?